# Foreign Key constraint on set of rows of a table data sql server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a `ValidationTable` like

[image]

and `OrderProcessing` table like

[image]

I want to create foreign key constraint on `OrderProcessing` table on column `OrderType` that references first 3 rows of `ValidationTable` (of `ValidationType` `= "orders"`).  Is this possible?  I referred similar questions but those did not really help.

Comment: The very definition of a foreign key indicates clearly this is not possible. Perhaps if you can explain clearly what you are trying to do we can help you find a solution that will work.

Comment: What are "the first three rows"? Those with IDs 1,2,3? You can achieve this kind of thing with a trigger, not a foreign key, but as Sean suggested it's not quite clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to link a specific set of rows.

The constraint has to be for the whole column.